# Match page source tags with regex

Tags: html, regex

I am trying to catch a tag from a page source with **regex**.
After allot of trying i find it very hard to establish.
Here is an example of an HTML source:

```
<div class="searchBx">
 <div>
  <li><a href="/" class="on">somthing</a></li>
 </div>
</div>
<div>
 <li><a href="/" class="on">somthing2</a></li>
</div>
```

I am trying to catch only the (div class="searchBx") tag and the tags inside.

It is hard because it always catch the div tag after him.
The result should be:

```
<div class="searchBx">
 <div>
  <li><a href="/" class="on">somthing</a></li>
 </div>
</div>
```

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Where is this div class "hidden" you speak of in your source. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Would "Match" be a better first word in the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible for regex to match the div you speak of.

Since the div contains another div, by nature it will not be able to differentiate between the `</div>` tag within it, or the `</div>` tag that closes the div you wish to match.

```
<div class="searchBx">
 <div>
  <li><a href="/" class="on">somthing</a></li>
 </div> <!-- This -->
</div> <!-- and this are the same to regex -->
<div>
 <li><a href="/" class="on">somthing2</a></li>
</div>
```

Here's what happens: http://regexr.com/3d0jn

For what you need to do, you must use a DOM parser in whichever language you are using.

Plus [it's incredibly poor practice using regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/), but everyone does it anyway.

Comment: Jeff Dean can parse HTML with Regular Expressions

Comment: I guess the natural question to follow that is "who's Jeff Dean?" And also, I'm not saying it's impossible, just not good practice.

Comment: Sorry, I just couldn't help writing it. It's a joke : regex are indeed not suited for html parsing (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1570104 for reference). Jeff Dean is a famous google engineer, widely known in the internet for "Jeff Dean's facts" (sort of Chuck Norris facts applied to computer science). See https://www.quora.com/What-are-all-the-Jeff-Dean-facts if you want to have some fun.

Comment: Oh okay man... I guess I'm a little too serious sometimes! ;) Good joke!